# Primefaces schedule how to customise DefaultScheduleEvent and create it's own event

Tags: primefaces

I'm currently implementing an event management application,and I'm using schedule componenet in primefaces 
http://primefaces.org:8080/showcase/ui/data/schedule.xhtml

but I want to crate my own event that has several attributes not only 3 as the DefaultScheduleEvent?

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your class's object and add it to the event

Example

```
eventModel = new DefaultScheduleModel();
/***create your object*/
yourclass obj1= new yourclass()
obj1.setattrib1('1');
obj1.setattrib2('2');
obj1.setattrib3('3');
/********/

/****add object to event (last parameter)*////
eventModel.addEvent(new DefaultScheduleEvent("Champions League Match", previousDay8Pm(), previousDay11Pm(),obj1));
```

to select...

```
public void onEventSelect(SelectEvent selectEvent) {
    event = (ScheduleEvent) selectEvent.getObject();
    yourclass ob1=(yourclass) event.getData();
}
```